# Pandas apply with running total in second column

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting a function to pandas that loops over a collection and updates each value based on a conditional and a running total. The function looks like this

```
def calculate_value():
    cumulative_amount = 0

    for row in rows:
        if row['amount'] < 0:
            return 0

        amount = 0

        if row['kind'] == 'A':
            amount = row['amount'] * row['input_amount']
        elif row['kind'] == 'B':
            amount = row['input_amount'] - cumulative_amount
        elif row['kind'] == 'C':
            amount = row['amount']

        cumulative_amount += amount
        row['result'] = amount

        if row['kind'] == 'B':
            break

    return rows
```

Basically, loop over all the rows, and add a `result` value. But this `result` may depend on a cumulative running total. Further, if we hit a certain value (`row['kind'] == 'B'`) we should break and stop processing new rows.

When converting this to pandas, it seems like I should be using `apply`. So far, I have the below code, which *almost* works, but when I try to get `cumulative_amount` with `shift(-1)`, it's always coming back as `nan`.

What's the best way to do this in pandas?

```
def calculate_value(row: Series):
    if row['amount'] < 0 or row.shift(-1)['kind'] == 'B':
        row['cumulative_amount'] = 0
        row['result'] = 0
        return row

    amount = 0

    if np.isnan(row.shift(-1)['cumulative_amount']):
        cumulative_amount = 0
    else:
        cumulative_amount = row.shift(-1)['cumulative_amount']

    if row['kind'] == 'A':
        amount = row['amount'] * row['input_amount']
    elif row['kind'] == 'B':
        amount = row['input_amount'] - cumulative_amount
    elif row['kind'] == 'C':
        amount = row['amount']

    row['cumulative_amount'] = amount + cumulative_amount
    row['result'] = amount
    return row

df['cumulative_amount'] = 0
new_df = df.apply(lambda x: calculate_value(x), axis=1)
```

An example of input and desired output are

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'kind': {1: 'C', 2: 'E', 3: 'A', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C'},
    'amount': {1: -800, 2: 100, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.5, 5: 0, 6: 200},
    'input_amount': {1: 800, 2: 800, 3: 800, 4: 800, 5: 800, 6: 800}
})

   amount  input_amount kind  cumulative_amount  result
1  -800.0           800    C                0.0     0.0
2   100.0           800    E                0.0     0.0
3     0.5           800    A              400.0   400.0
4     0.5           800    A              800.0   400.0
5     0.0           800    B              800.0     0.0
6   200.0           800    C              800.0     0.0
```

Comment: Can you provide a same input dataframe and expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston done.

Comment: `apply` does not seem like a good approach here, since it works row-by-row and is not expected to access other rows of the dataframe during computation. Your initial solution looks absolutely fine to me.

Comment: @MartinValgur I am not a pandas expert, but I was under the impression that doing that was a bad idea. People often cite [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) which says, "You should never modify something you are iterating over." I've updated my code to use `iterrows()` and `df.set_value` and it's working as expected, but I'm unclear if this is the best way to do things or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, only `result` for kind `'B'` depends on other rows. So you can start by doing everything else first:

```
df['result'] = 0.

a = (df.kind == 'A') & (df.amount >= 0) 
c = (df.kind == 'C') & (df.amount >= 0)

df.loc[a, 'result'] = df.loc[a, 'amount'] * df.loc[a, 'input_amount']
df.loc[c, 'result'] = df.loc[c, 'amount']
```

Do the cumsum:

```
df['cumulative_amount'] = df.result.cumsum()
```

Correct the value of `'cumulative_amount'` (for *all* occurrences  of  type  `'B'`):

```
df.loc[(df.kind == 'B'), 'result'] = df.loc[(df.kind == 'B'), 'input_amount'].values - df.loc[(df.kind.shift(-1) == 'B'), 'cumulative_amount'].values
```

Correct the values of `'result'` and `'cumulative_amount'` after the first occurrence of `'B'`:

```
df.loc[(df.kind == 'B').cumsum().shift() > 0, 'result'] = 0
# (df.kind == 'B').cumsum().shift() is a running count of the number of B's encountered prior to the row index, 
# so you want to 'stop' once this number is no longer zero
# You could of course do this more simply by figuring out which position in the index has the first B, 
# then using .ix or .iloc, but it's actually longer to type out.

df['cumulative_amount'] = df.result.cumsum() # Once more, because we've changed the value of results below B.
```