# Update a dataframe within apply after using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to group on and then update the original dataframe using `iterrows` and `set_value`. This doesn't appear to work.

Here is an example.

```
In [1]: def func(df, n):
   ...:     for i, row in df.iterrows():
   ...:         print("Updating {0} with value {1}".format(i, n))
   ...:         df.set_value(i, 'B', n)

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [0, 0]})

In [3]: df
Out[4]:
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  0

In [125]: func(df, 1)
Updating 0 with value 1
Updating 1 with value 1

In [126]: df
Out[126]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1

In [127]: df.groupby('A').apply(lambda df: func(df, 2))
Updating 0 with value 2
Updating 0 with value 2
Updating 1 with value 2
In [126]: df
Out[126]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
```

I was hoping that `B` would have been updated to `2`.

Why isn't this working, and what is the best way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have things written, you seem to want the function `func(df, n)` to modify `df` in place. But `df.groupby('A')` (in some sense) creates another set of dataframes (one for each group), so using `func()` as an argument to `df.groupby('A').apply()` only modifies the these newly created dataframes and not the original `df`. Furthermore, the returned dataframe is a concatenation of the outputs of `func()` called with each group as an argument, which is why the returned dataframe is empty.

The shortest fix to your problem is to `return df` at the end of `func`:

```
def func(df, n):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        print("Updating {0} with value {1}".format(i, n))
        df.set_value(i, 'B', n)
    return df
df = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda df: func(df, 2))
```

I presume this is not exactly what you had in mind because you're probably expecting to modify everything in place. If modifying everything in place is your intention, you'd need to use combinations of a `for` loop and `.loc`, but modifying your dataframe with `.loc` will be computationally expensive if you intend to call `.loc` many times.

I would also guess that your function to set values depends on a more complicated criterion, but usually you can vectorize things and avoid having to  use `.iterrows()` altogether.

To avoid the XY problem, I'd suggest describing your function in more detail, because chances are that you can get everything done with a few lines incorporating the use of `.loc` and avoiding the need to iterate through every row in Python. Case in point: `df['B'] = 2` (sans a `print` statement) is a one-liner solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The function I am trying to apply is described in [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871129/pandas-apply-with-running-total-in-second-column) I never got an official answer there, but a comment indicated that looping was a good solution to the problem. Unfortunately I need to apply that on a higher level (the column I am grouping on). Let me know if you have any ideas about the best way to implement this.

Comment: I've answered your other question. To beat a dead horse, `.iterrows()` is really a last resort that you often won't need (it sort of contradicts the purpose of Pandas, which is vectorization), and if it comes to it, `.itertuples()` usually works better.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because you are altering the copied subsets of `df` delivered by the `groupby` object's `get_group` method. You are changing something, just not what you were expecting.

If that weren't reason enough not to do this, you'll notice you had 3 print statements. That's because pandas runs that first group once to test and infer output. Then again to actually do stuff. If you altered things outside the scope , you may end up with unintended consequences.

Someone else can provide a better example of how to do it. I just wanted to explain why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations, if `func()` does things based on index, you could modify the original dataframe directly.

Instead of this:

```py
def func(group, n):
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        print("Updating {0} with value {1}".format(i, n))
        group.set_value(i, 'B', n)
    return group

df.groupby('A').apply(lambda group: func(group, 2))
```

You could do this:

```py
for key, group in df.groupby('A'):
    n = 2
    for i, row in group.iterrows():
        print("Updating {0} with value {1}".format(i, n))
        df.set_value(i, 'B', n)
```